# Baseball Player Set Puzzle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

So here's the problem:

In a survey of the chewing gum tastes of a group of baseball players, how many baseball players were surveyed with following results:

```
22 liked juicy fruit
25 liked spearmint
39 liked bubble gum
9 like both spearmint and juicy fruit
17 liked juicy fruit and bubble gum
20 liked spearmint and bubble gum
6 liked all three
4 liked none of these
```

I added up 9, 17, 20, 6, and 4 to get 56 but I have a feeling that's not the right way to do this problem... Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will be
$$
(22+25+39+4) - (9+17+20) + 6 = 50
$$
The second term there reflects the fact that the first term double-counts anybody who liked 2 of the three flavors.  The third term reflects the fact that somebody who likes 3 flavors will, in the first two terms, have been triple-counted and then subtracted off three times so it needs to be added back in.

Comment: @James  The idea behind this answer is often called the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much to all of you intelligent, kind souls!!!!